# Can I hard wire an IR remote directly into the receiver?

Tags: infrared, wire, modulation

I have a IR remote control and a clock (which it is designed to control.) I would like to remove the IR LED from the remote and the sensor from the clock, and run a wire between the two (so the clock can be controlled from another room.)  I thought this would be easy, but there are a few issues (like the LED having 2 leads and the sensor having 3.)  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just extend remote's IR LED with a wire and place it near the receiver? It would be the safest way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that directly because the LED signal is modulated on a (most commonly) 36 kHz or 38 kHz carrier, which is removed by the receiver. You could insert a circuit that removes the carrier, but from your question I guess that you don't have much experience in electronics, so I would't go that route.

Jodes' suggestion is by far the most practical. If you put the IR LED realy close, you might need to put a resistor in series with the IR LED to avoid overdriving the receiver (for a start, try 1k).